# Issue in hash modification

Tags: perl, hash

I am printing a hash `[ print Dumper($myhash); ]`, it is as below :

```
$VAR1= {
  'context_verdict' => 'Failed',
  'logfile' => 'abc',
  'Block_000' => {
     'Element_0032' => {
         'e_verdict' => 'FAILED',
         'e_name' => 'Element_0032',
         'e_log' => 'This is really bad...',
         'e_ref' => 'Good'
     }
  }
```

Now I want to change the value of logfile from abc to def. how to achieve this ?

I wrote

```
$myhash{'$VAR1'}->{'logfile'}="def";
```

But it does not works!! It is still the "abc".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$myhash->{'logfile'}="def";
```

Data::Dumper names your variable as $VAR1, this is not an entry in your hash.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

You want

```
$VAR1->{'logfile'} = "def";
```

If you obtained the dump using `Dumper(\%myhash)`,

```
$myhash{'logfile'} = "def";
```

If you obtained the dump using `Dumper($myhash)`,

```
$myhash->{'logfile'} = "def";
```

`$myhash` holds a reference to a hash, so you need to dereference it to access the hash. That's what `->` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

`Data::Dumper` helps to analyse a huge hash and the values will be named **$VAR** in the output.

Answer to your question is:

You can set the value as

```
   $myhash->{'logfile'}="def";
```